# A large update statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, batch-processing

I have to do an update statement on a table with a large number of records for 3 years, each month has a million of records.

I have tried to use the batching script but it takes a long time and I cancel it before the end.

Could you please suggest the most efficient way to do this task?

Thank you in advance.

Regards,

The main code of the treatment is:

```
UPDATE [XXXX_DWH].[Dwh].[Invoice]
SET OrderingCustomerCode = SUBSTRING(orderingcustomercode, 2, 7)
WHERE InvoicingYear = '2019' AND InvoicingMonth = '01'
```

Comment: How does your indexing look like? Also, how many indexes do you have on that table? And how many of them contain the `OrderingCustomerCode` column?

Comment: Yes - you need to explain more about what indexes exist. Why do you stop it before the end? Why not let it run?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few possibilities. If you have to change the whole table it may be faster to create a copy of your table with your change and then rename the table (recreate all the indexes etc to make the objects the same). If only a part of the table must be changed you can insert rows you want to change to another table, delete these rows from Invoice and then insert them back to Invoice from a temporary table.

```
select col1, col2, SUBSTRING(orderingcustomercode, 2, 7) as orderingcustomercode ... the rest of columns
into [XXXX_DWH].[Dwh].[Invoice_temp]
from [XXXX_DWH].[Dwh].[Invoice]
```

Updating only let's say 100 000 at a time should also be a good option, but if you have a millions of rows in a columnstore index the first approach is better in my opinion. Batches decreases transaction logs genereted by an update. It also be good to enable sql server to search this `where InvoicingYear='2019' and InvoicingMonth='01'` for i.e. having a partitioning on InvoiceDate.

```
DECLARE @output INT = 1

while @output > 0
begin
with cte as 
    (select top 100000 *
    from [XXXX_DWH].[Dwh].[Invoice]
    where InvoicingYear='2019' and InvoicingMonth='01')
update cte
set OrderingCustomerCode=SUBSTRING(orderingcustomercode,2,7)

SET @output = @@ROWCOUNT

end
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, in this case we can use the 'SELECT INTO' to use a temporary table with our changes (column that will be updated) and then use a delete on the originally table (Invoice) for the concerned years and then do an insert statement from the temporary table to the Invoice table.

Comment: Yes, that sounds reasonable. As a 'temporary' I mean a normal table, but one that will be deleted after the job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the insert statement takes also a long time, could we use directly the update on each month by using for example the indexes?

Comment: Ani Index won't help, with so mamy rows SQL serwer will scan the table anyway (cheaper then index seeks and lookups). I don't knows specific of your environment, but it looks to me that it's a big work for your server, so there no silver bullet to this. You can still go for updates in batches. Run it in the morninng and wait. An advantage of this is that you can always kill it and some rows will be updated or run it after hours and check it after a few hours.

Comment: You've got it backwards. If a table scan produces a lot of rows and an index produces a lot less... it will help and it will be used. But we're all just making assumptions here - there's not enough info in the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. The main object is to find the efficient way to do an update on a big table (informations about the records has been specified and abtou the indexes we use it in the PS but i ma not familiarized with them), the suggesstion of  M. Kanarkowski will help by using temporary table and insert statement.Thank you all.